# How to li element move into the preceding-sibling 'p' element - XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

If following-sibling `li` element of `p` then how to move `li` element?
**Input**

```
<root>
<p>start</p>
<p>aaaaa</p>
<li>aaa</li>
<li>bbb</li>
<li>ccc</li>
<p>aaaaa</p>
<p>aaaaaa</p>
```

**Expected Output**

```
<root>
<p>start</p>
<p>aaaaa
    <li>aaa</li>
    <li>bbb</li>
    <li>ccc</li>
</p>
<p>aaaaa</p>
<p>aaaaaa</p>
```

**XSLT:**

```
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
    <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*[1][self::li]">
            <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::*[1][self::li]">
                <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:if>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Why do you have an "al" node created in your template? I don't see any "al" node in your required output.

Comment: @Sebastien, I have edit my question please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you can use XSLT-2.0, you can make use of `xsl:for-each-group`. So the following is one way to achieve the desired result:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:output indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
  
    <xsl:template match="p[name(following-sibling::*[1]) = 'li']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
            <xsl:for-each-group select="following-sibling::*" group-adjacent="name()">
                <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()" />
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
  
    <xsl:template match="li[preceding-sibling::*[1] = (preceding-sibling::p[1] | preceding-sibling::li[1])]" />
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <p>start</p>
   <p>aaaaa<li>aaa</li>
      <li>bbb</li>
      <li>ccc</li>
   </p>
   <p>aaaaa</p>
   <p>aaaaaa</p>
</root>
```

Comment: Sir, @zx485 Thanks for the reply. Can you check last 2 liens if li element not preceding-sibling p element then not S/B delete li element (https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nb9NXUL/2).

Comment: Thanks Sir, Give me solution!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way you could do it that would also work in XSLT 1.0.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- P node that has a li node directly below it -->
  <xsl:template match="p[following-sibling::*[1][self::li]]">
      <xsl:variable name="id" select="generate-id(.)"/>
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <!-- Copy all li nodes that share the same p as their preceding-sibling -->
        <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::li[generate-id(preceding-sibling::p[1]) = $id]"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="li"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nb9NXUL/3

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you check last 2 liens if li element not preceding-sibling p element then not S/B delete li element (https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nb9NXUL/1).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you just want

```
  <xsl:template match="root">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="p">
              <xsl:copy>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="node(), tail(current-group())"/>
              </xsl:copy>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNvt6XN

The `tail` function would not be supported by an XSLT 2 processor but of course `current-group()[position() gt 1]` can be used instead.

Comment: Sir, Please check last line if edit my input last element change then should not be move to previous element. (https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNvt6XN/1)

Comment: @Sam, consider to edit your question with the input you have and the output you want.